# How can I avoid having lots of if statements when finding combinations of radio buttons?

Tags: python, if-statement, radio-button, logic, control-flow

I have a database that looks like this:

| Rat | Age | RA | RB | RAB | RC | RD | RCD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | None | None | Mild | Severe | None | Death |
| B | 2 | Mild | Severe | Severe | None | Mild | Severe |

RA stands for reaction to substance A, RB reaction to substance B, RAB reaction to substances A and B at the same time etc - there are more than A-D substances but for time I haven't listed them here

I'm developing a GUI that will allow the user to select a rat from a list of radio buttons, then choose any number and combination of substances (e.g. A, B, C, E or A, D, F) and I want to display the reaction the selected rat has to the selected substances.

At the moment I've got an if statement for every single possible combination of substance, which is getting a bit silly. I did think about a switch statement but this would also be very long. There's no particular logic to what combination of substances cause which reaction in each rat. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: If you have a list of all the substances, concatenate them with `'R' + ''.join(sorted(substances))` and use that as the column name in the database.

Comment: @user19077881In a database. The rows are different rats. Rat B has a reaction to substance A

Comment: @Barmar What if the user selected A, B and D though - I don't have a column for all three combined, just A + B, and D separately.

Comment: I assumed you had columns for all the possibilities. What is the result supposed to be if they select a combination that doesn't exist?

Comment: @Barmar then I want to view the subset of combinations that do exist and the ones that aren't combinations separately. So if A, B and D were selected the combination of A and B, then D separately

Comment: And if AB says mild, while D says severe, you just accept the contradiction?

Comment: @Barmar You show both results yes

Answer (score 0):

If you can map the combinations of substances to the reactions for each rat in a dictionary like this:

```
    reactions = {
        'A': {
            ('A',): 'None',
            ('B',): 'None',
            ('A', 'B'): 'Mild',
            ('C',): 'Severe',
            ('D',): 'Death',
            ('C', 'D'): 'Severe'
            # ...
        },
        'B': {
            ('A',): 'Mild',
            ('B',): 'Severe',
            ('A', 'B'): 'Severe',
            ('C',): 'None',
            ('D',): 'Mild',
            ('C', 'D'): 'Severe'
            # ...
        }
        # other rats
    }
```

Then

```
reaction = reactions[selected_rat].get(tuple(selected_substances), 'None')
```

will give you the reaction for the selected rat and substances from the GUI where `selected_rat` is of type `str`, and `selected_substances` is of type `list` containing `str` elements.

Comment: Would this work if the user selected A, B and D, for example?

So it would return A+B: Mild, D: death for rat A? Or would it try and find a combination of A+B+D?

Comment: @LozCodes It's going to find the combination of A,B,D and for rat A there is no such combination.

Comment: Ah okay - I need it to find the combination A and B, then D separately

Comment: @LozCodes Suppose there is not any combination among A,B,C? What would be the result in this case?

Comment: The A, B and C all separately, if there is no combination between them